# serialize/unserialize problem with file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have a bunch of multidimensional arrays serialized and saved in one txt file, one per line.
Now, I'm reading the file with `file_get_contents` but when I unserialize the variable with the content of the file, it echos only the first line of the file.

In debug, the file's content is readed entirely, it's only when I unserialize the variable that I get only the first array. I think there is some problem with the `\n\r` that I add at the end of the line for starting a new one, 'cause if I delete the first line, it read the next one correctly, but just the first again!

For the `\n\r` mentioned before, I first writed the array serialized in the file, after I append a `\n\r` with `file_put_contents($this->logFile,"\r\n",FILE_APPEND)`. Is this correct?

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Im not sure I understnad it well, you serialize a bunch of arrays, put them into a file, then read the file and try to unserialize as a whole ? Youd better read and unserialize each line from the file ...

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do. I know that I can read the file line by line and unserialize but I'm just curious why the unserialize function act like this!

Comment: I agree with @yent, but it may be more worthwhile to use [var_export](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to the file and treat it like a standard include file.

Comment: Because the docs mention `unserialize() takes a **single** serialized variable and converts it back into a PHP value. `

Comment: may be you shld go for a loop structure...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of [`unserialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). per the docs:

> unserialize() takes a single serialized variable and converts it back into a PHP value.

(note the use of **single**)

You do have a couple of options though:

- Use [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) and reach each line and unserialize it individually.
- Use [`var_export`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to the file and then treat that save file like a typical include.

Comment: Ok I used `file` and make a foreach thru all the lines (3 in this case), and now all is printed out perfect!
Thanks